# Multiply RelativeLayout in vertical LinearLayout by code

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app that consists of a LinearLayout which should contain several RelativeLayouts.

Below you see the code of the RelativeLayout which is supposed to be multiplied several times. How code I do this by Java code?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtName1"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="TextView" />                

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit1"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txtName1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/edit1" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int FIRST_ROW_ID = 100;
    private static final int SECOND_ROW_ID = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout layoutContainer = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_container);

        View firstRow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_part, layoutContainer, false);
        View secondRow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_part, layoutContainer, false);

        firstRow.setId(FIRST_ROW_ID);
        secondRow.setId(SECOND_ROW_ID);

        layoutContainer.addView(firstRow);
        layoutContainer.addView(secondRow);

        EditText editText = firstRow.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        editText.setText("Hello");

        EditText editText2 = secondRow.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        editText2.setText("World");
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

`layout_part.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txtName1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/edit1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I am doing here is relatively simple: The `root layout (activity_main.xml)` just defines the `LinearLayout`. It will be the container holding all the rows.

To create the rows without having to declare every property via Java code I extracted the `RelativeLayout` and put it in a separate file (`layout_part.xml`).

Now in the Activity I just intialize the `layoutContainer` and then `inflate` the `layout of the row` as often as needed. Note that the third parameter (`attachToRoot`) is false `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_part, layoutContainer, false)`.

The reasoning behind this is the following: If it was set to true, the layout would immediately be added to the `layoutContainer` and therefore id's would not be unique (you would have several editText1 ids for example). So I tell the inflater: Hey I will add those `Views` myself once I am ready.

So how are the ids going to be unique? Well just assign a different id to each of the inflated layouts.

Afterwards just add the rows to the `layoutContainer` and then I have just set a text on the `EditText` of each row to prove that this is working.

That's it! If you have further questions - just ask :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Rene and your proposed solution which works out fine. I added a variable    View[] Rows so I can easily refer to the respective rows and reduce the lines of code

Comment: One more question: How I have to change the code if I like to perform the same action in a fragment @Rene ? I get a "null-object" error for the layoutContainer.add method.